# Swift Realm Results Convert to Model

Tags: swift, realm

Is there any simple way to map a Realm request to a Swift Model (struct) when it is just a single row?

When it is an array of data I can do something like this and work with the array.  This is not working on a single row.

```
func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return compactMap { $0 as? T }
}
```

But what is best to do when just a single row of data?

my databases are big so doing it manually is just a pain and ugly.

It would also be nice when the Swift Model is not 100% the same as the Realm Model.  Say one has 30 elements and the other only 20.  Just match up the required data.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a single row of data? Do you mean a single property? Or are you trying to convert each realm object into a struct?

Comment: Realm is returning a single row of values.  (About 40 or them.)

Comment: Realm does not have rows as such so what's being asked is a bit unclear. Also, you want to avoid array's when working with Realm as is disconnects the object from Realm. What does *doing it manually is just a pain and ugly* mean specifically. Do you have some example code of what you're saying? What's the problem with using Realm Objects - what do you mean by 'Swift Models'? Please update and clarify the question as the answer may be super simple but we need to understand the use case.

Answer (score 0):

On my apps I m using this class to do all actions. I hope that's a solution for your situation. There is main actions for realm.

```
Usage 

class Test: Object {
    var name: String?
}

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let realm = CoreRealm()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let data = realm.getArray(selectedType: Test.self)
    }
```

```
import RealmSwift

class CoreRealm {
    
// Usage Example:
//    let testObject = RealmExampleModel(value: ["age":1 , "name":"Name"])
//    let testSubObject = TestObject(value: ["name": "FerhanSub", "surname": "AkkanSub"])
//    testObject.obje.append(testSubObject)
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    func deleteDatabase() {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
        }
    }
    
    func delete<T: Object>(selectedType: T.Type) {
        try! realm.write {
            let object = realm.objects(selectedType)
            realm.delete(object)
        }
    }
    
    func delete<T: Object>(selectedType: T.Type, index: Int) {
        try! realm.write {
            let object = realm.objects(selectedType)
            realm.delete(object[index])
        }
    }
    
    func add<T: Object>(_ selectedObject: T) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(selectedObject)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    // return Diretly object
    func getArray<T: Object>(selectedType: T.Type) -> [T]{
        let object = realm.objects(selectedType)
        var array = [T]()
        for data in object {
            array.append(data)
        }
        return array
    }
    
    func getObject<T: Object>(selectedType: T.Type, index: Int) -> T{
        let object = realm.objects(selectedType)
        var array = [T]()
        for data in object {
            array.append(data)
        }
        return array[index]
    }
    
    // return Result tyle
    func getResults<T: Object>(selectedType: T.Type) -> Results<T> {
        return realm.objects(selectedType)
    }
    
    func getResult<T: Object>(selectedType: T.Type) -> T? {
        return realm.objects(selectedType).first
    }
    
    func createJsonToDB<T: Object>(jsonData data: Data, formatType: T.Type) {
//        let data = "{\"name\": \"San Francisco\", \"cityId\": 123}".data(using: .utf8)!
        let realm = try! Realm()
        
        try! realm.write {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                realm.create(formatType, value: json, update: .modified)
            } catch {
                print("Json parsing error line 65")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While all answers are appreciated, I am not sure how this applies. This appears to be a singleton to read and write objects. However, the code disconnects those objects from Realm when read which removes the live-updating nature of realm. The delete at index function is going to be an issue - realm does not guarantee order of objects without a sort. So if you tell realm to delete an object at index `T', that object may not be in that position each time it's read and the order can change. Also, why store an encoded JSON object in realm; it won't be queryable? Just trying to understand the code.

Comment: Actulay createJSONToDb function has written for specific senario. For delete actions also needs to get firstly all table from db then delete sepcific index. Because in when you add any object in DB it adds them in order. Cause that we need to read it firstly.  JSON is queryable because we give format type you can call it with format type.

Comment: *when you add any object in DB it adds them in order* - is unfortunately not correct. Realm makes no guarantee of object order. The only ordering that's enforced is in a `List` collection or if you leverage a .sort. See the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#sorting) which states *Note that the order of Results is only guaranteed to stay consistent when the query is sorted. For performance reasons, insertion order is not guaranteed to be preserved*